# Summing rolls of three distinct dice and gets $a$, $b$, and $c$. Find the probability of $2a + b + c = 10$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Summing rolls of three distinct dice and gets $a$, $b$, and $c$. Find the probability of $2a + b + c = 10$.

My answer:

a b c
4 1 1
3 2 2
2 3 3
1 4 4

3 3 1
3 1 3
2 1 5
2 5 1

2 4 2
2 2 4
1 5 3
1 3 5

Total $12$ cases out of $6^3 \implies $ probability is $1/18$. Is this correct? Please check.

Comment: It's poor practice to use the title exclusively to give a problem statement.  Indeed the full problem statement should appear in the body of the Question, regardless of whether the title gives a terse version of the problem.

Comment: You should get $7+5+3 +1 = 16$.

Answer (score 3):

No. You forgot $1,2,6$ and $1,6,2$

I think you would not have missed those had you generated the combination a little more systematically. That is, starting with $a=4$ ( which is clearly the maximum for $a$), you indeed get only one option: $4,1,1$. OK, so let's move to $a=3$. Now let's figure out all options with that, starting with the highest possible value of $b$: $3,3,1$, $3,2,2$, $3,1,3$, and that's it. And only now go down to $a=2$, etc. Indeed, doing this, I immediately spotted the missing two combinations.

Looking at your combinations, there is a certain systematicity to it ... but not enough.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{a = 1}^{6}{1 \over 6}
\sum_{b = 1}^{6}{1 \over 6}\sum_{c = 1}^{6}
{1 \over 6}\bracks{z^{10}}z^{2a + b + c}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 216}\bracks{z^{10}}
\bracks{\sum_{a = 1}^{6}\pars{z^{2}}^{a}}
\pars{\sum_{b = 1}^{6}z^{b}}\pars{\sum_{b = 1}^{6}z^{c}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 216}\bracks{z^{10}}
\pars{z^{2}\,{z^{12} - 1 \over z^{2} - 1}}
\pars{z\,{z^{6} - 1 \over z - 1}}
\pars{z\,{z^{6} - 1 \over z - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 216}\bracks{z^{6}}{-z^{24} + 2z^{18} - 2z^{6} + 1 \over
\pars{1 - z^{2}}\pars{1 - z}^{2}} =
{1 \over 216}\bracks{z^{6}}{-2z^{6} + 1 \over
\pars{1 - z^{2}}\pars{1 - z}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 108} + {1 \over 216}\,\bracks{z^{6}}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}z^{2m}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-2 \choose  n}\pars{-z}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 108} + {1 \over 216}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{2 + n - 1\choose  n}
\pars{-1}^{n}}\pars{-1}^{n}\bracks{2m + n = 6}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 108} + {1 \over 216}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{n + 1}
\bracks{n = 6 - 2m}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 108} + {1 \over 216}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\pars{7 - 2m}\bracks{6 - 2m \geq 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 108} + {1 \over 216}
\sum_{m = 0}^{3}\pars{7 - 2m} =
\bbx{7 \over 108} \approx 0.0648
\end{align}

> ---

[image]

It means $\ds{\bbx{{14 \over 6 \times 6 \times 6} = {7 \over 108}}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By parity, you know that b and c are both even or both odd.

From here, consider the *stars and bars* method of counting (multichoose). There will be an edge case or two, but this will simplify your job significantly.